# How to push all lower elements down when expanding a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a video iframe that expands when clicking a button. This is contained inside of a header for the page which has 100vh height (full screen). When the video expands, it pushes the rest of the content in the header up in order to have everything vertically centred within the header. Instead, I would like to increase the height of the header div beyond 100vh to 100vh plus the video height. However, the code I have so far isn't working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".video" ).click(function() {    
        $(".header").height("+=315");
        document.getElementById("video__player").style.maxHeight = "50vw";
        
        document.getElementById("video-btn").style.display = "none";      
    });
});
```

```css
.header {height: 100vh; width: 100vw;}

.header__content {height: calc(100vh); width: 100%; display: flex; display: -webkit-flex;}
.header__content--container {margin: auto; display: flex; display: -webkit-flex; flex-direction: column; -webkit-flex-direction: column;}
.video__container {text-align: center;}
.video {color: gray; width: 100%; height: auto;}
.play-btn {width: 20px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle;}
.video__player {overflow: hidden; width: 300px; max-height: 0px; transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="header">
                
                <div class="header__menu">
                    <div class="header__menu--left">
                        <div class="logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header__menu--right">
                        <div class="phone">
                        </div>
                            <h8 class="strong" style="margin: auto;">Get your quote</h6>
                        </a>
                        <div class="language">
                            <h9 class="clickable strong" style="color: #5CBDE1;">FR</h9>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="header__content">
                    <div class="header__content--container animatedParent animateOnce">
                        <br><br>
                        <div class="quote__wrapper header__quote--wrapper">
                            
                                <h8 class="strong" style="margin: auto;">Get your quote</h6>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>
                        <div class="video__container animated fadeInDownShort slow">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
```

Comment: Snippet is complaining that `$` is not defined.

Comment: @OliviaRuth the snippet won't work so well as many of the styles are not set. It is better to use the link I provided.

Comment: How is that going to work? You have the copy sitting in the DOM above the video. If you want it to shift below then you are going to have the text traverse the video - which is going to look weird.

Instead, you could just create a hidden div below the video that contains the same text as above, and then when clicking to start the video, you hide the top text and reveal the bottom text.

Comment: @Korgrue I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I want everything above the video to stay where it is on expand. Everything below the video should shift down. Maybe I could increase the height of the header div with javascript according to the change in height of the expanding div?

Comment: Have you looked into using JQuery's `animate` to change the height instead of just changing the value? You can specify the animation style, and try one that meets what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `margin` of `.header__content--container` is currently set to `auto`. Change the margin to some hard-coded value like, for example, `300px`, and it works like you want it to.

EDIT: the requested function

```
function setMarginTop() {
    const $header = $(".header__content--container");
    const marginTop = $header.css("margin-top");
    $header.css("margin-top", marginTop);
}
```

Comment: Ok so the margin is set to auto. Is there a way I can capture the actual value of the top margin with javascript when the button is clicked, then set the margin-top to keep that value with javascript?

Comment: After testing, changing margin to a set value keeps everything static on the page. Possibly a step in the right direction, but not quite the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: In that case I recommend moving the div containing the iframe outside of the `header` div, otherwise what you're asking is not possible.

Comment: What about the edit I just made to the code I have so far. Why can't I just increase the height of the header div by the height of the expanding div?